# How to use/enable EventHubsEventSource traces for EventHubClient in Azure servicebus

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

In the source code of EventHubClient (from Azure SDK) ([LINK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/EventHubClient.cs#L79)) I see that there are diagnostic traces in part of the function calls. I want to find out how I can enable this so that the traces show up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out how I can enable this so that the traces show up somewhere.

You need to implement a EventListener to save the logs to anywhere you want. Following is a sample of writing logs to a file.

```
public sealed class FileEventListener : EventListener
{
    private string _filePath;

    public FileEventListener(string name)
    {
        this._filePath = name;
    }

    private void WriteToFile(string message)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(_filePath, DateTime.Now.ToString() + message + "\n");
    }

    protected override void OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
    {
        WriteToFile(string.Format(eventData.Message, eventData.Payload.ToArray()));  
    }

    protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
    {

    }
}
```

After implemented your own EventListener, you could use it in your application.

```
EventListener myFileListener = new FileEventListener("D:\\log.txt");
myFileListener.EnableEvents(EventHubsEventSource.Log, EventLevel.LogAlways);
```

Comment: Any update? If my reply help you solve your issue, please mark it as answer.